# How do I make my Hatchi weigh more?

Tags: android, hatchi

I'm currently on the second stage of evolution (child) and I want to get my [Hatchi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.portablepixels.hatchi) up to 13lbs or more in weight. The problem is, even if I keep feeding it meat, the weight is stuck at 12.7lbs.

I'm on the Android version of the game at v1.05. As of right now, I ensure that all the bars on top are filled in, plus I feed it whenever I have the chance.

What do I need to do to make it weigh over that 13lbs?

Comment: @Sorean Your tag wiki suggestions were okay; it was just the tag that's wrong. If you suggest them again for [tag:hatchi], you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in v1.05 which stops the weight being displayed correctly. Your weight still goes up but you can't see it. The next release due very soon will fix this.